# Debugging perl CGI

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, cgi, xampp

I am using a web form I created as an interface to query a MySQL database. I have written some 
perl CGI scripts to process the queries. But I am not getting the desired output, so I need to 
debug the scripts. How do I do that? I mostly use Eclipse for debugging perl, but now I have the
web form parameters (checkboxes, listboxes) as input to the script. Is there any way I can pass 
in the inputs from the web page and then debug the script in Eclipse? Or is there any other way 
of debugging in this case? Hope I have made myself clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course you can use Apaches error log to do debugging; which a very lazy but efficient way to work.

You mention you use Eclipse so I assume you also use the EPIC plug-in for Perl development. Check out this chapter on how to configure Eclipse/EPIC for debugging CGI:

http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch06s02.php

Comment: This link is just what I was looking for! Somehow I could not find it myself. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

I use [this Perl module](https://github.com/DeeNewcum/individual_scripts/blob/master/perl_modules/capture_CGI_input.pm) for CGI debugging.  It lets you capture all data sent to a CGI script, when running from a normal browser.  It then lets you "replay" the script from anywhere (command line, within a debugger) using the captured data.

[CGI::Inspect](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aInspect) looks promising, though I haven't tried it yet myself.

Using [Devel::DumpTrace](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aDumpTrace) during a normal CGI session (with the data being logged to a file, via DUMPTRACE_FH) is a way to do in-depth debugging, without using an actual debugger.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly you want to debug, but a few tips:

- When running under Apache, warnings go to the `error.log`, so you could follow your variables there.
- The CGI.pm module allows you to [run CGI scripts from the command-line (with parameters)](http://p3rl.org/CGI#DEBUGGING).

Answer (score 1):

I would hope Eclipse has a way to simulate CGI.

I use ActiveState's Komodo IDE, and it can simulate CGI (including input params), so I can recommend that as a good tool for this purpose.  The IDE is NOT free, though, but consider this an investment if you're going to be doing this a lot.  (I'm NOT affiliated with ActiveState - just a happy customer.)

Comment: I also use Komodo.  Simulating CGI is helpful in very specific cases, but I also have used Komodo's remote debugging capabilities.  I basically have Perl run in debug mode on a development server and point it to the Komodo debugger on my machine.  That way I can step through my CGI script as it is running on the web server itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but one reason I use Eclipse is because its free. And it turns out I can simulate CGI in Eclipse just as in Komodo (see the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

if you have a hypothetical CGI program written in perl, called webawesome.pl and you want to pass it two parameters: name and age, you can use a shell command like this:

```
prompt> perl -d webawesome.pl name=sifl age=21
```

Now you're in the perl debugger and you can step through your program, and the key/value pairs from the command line will be loaded as form parameters by CGI.pm

Setting these command line switches in Eclipse is left as an exercise to the reader, as I am an unabashed vi user, and haven't use eclipse in two or three years.  I know there's dialogs to set run/debug options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug or Fiddler to watch your requests made from the form, to ensure you are sending exactly what you think you are. You can also open a file `open(fh,">>debug.txt")` and print out the sql calls that you are making to a log file.  I would also suggest learning about Data::Dumper which will print out objects prettily so you can see their structure.